# How To Join Unrelated Table and Show in Gridview Yii2

Tags: yii2

Table A

```
id   name   age
--   ----   ---
 1    a      9
 2    b      11
 3    c      10
```

Table B

```
id   name   address
--   ------   -------
1    aa       abc
1    aa       efg
3    bb       hij
```

Table C

```
id   name   address   age   
--   ------   -------   ---   
 1    aa       abc       9     
 1    aa       efg       9     
 2    NULL     NULL      11    
 3    bb       hij       10
```

how can i join this unrelated table become like this :
Table D

```
    id   name   address   age  
    ---  ----   -------   ---- 
     1    a      null      9
     2    b      null      11
     3    c      null      10
     1    aa     abc      null
     1    aa     efg      null
     3    bb     hij      null
     1    aa     abc       9     
     1    aa     efg       9     
     2    NULL   NULL      11    
     3    bb     hij       10
```

if you have some refference to read how to create controller, model and search model, i will be so glad..thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to you sample seems you need  an union between the 3 tables

```
$sql = "select  id, name, address, age
    from table_c
    union all 
    select  id, name, address, null 
    from table_b
    union all
    select  id, name, null, age
    from table_a;";
```

and you could use a raw SQL command to retrieve the query rows

```
  $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
  $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
  $result = $command->queryAll();
```

In `$result` you obtain an array and each array element is an array representing a row of data.

Comment: Thx my friend, but any way to use active record?

Comment: @SuhariAdi see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31017595/yii2-how-to-create-activedataprovider-with-union-query-and-sorting) post to use active query with `union`

Comment: thx https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731614/muhammad-omer-aslam .. thats a right thread to my question..